# Differentiating Equation containing modulo operation

Tags: back-emf

(DC motor Single Loop setup)
[image]

I have the equation for flux containing mod operation of the angle as an independent variable.

[image]

the graph:
[image]

The textbook then directly derives the derivative of flux for the calculation of emf as follows:

[image]

My question is, where did the mod go after differentiation?

Comment: I feel this is actually more of a Math Exchange problem, depending on how picky you want to get at the borders of the singularity. But in practice you could probably just ignore it since you know it loops around and repeats (if you understand what modulo does, anyways) and the slope on either side of the singularity so the function of the slope could be treated as continuous.

Comment: so it means slope at discontinuities is the same so I can ignore it.

Comment: For engineering purposes you can, for mathematical purposes...well...mathematicians are more careful and picky. For example, for the top discontinuity, is the point just to the left of it the infinite slope? Or does it actually just tie into the lower discontinuity? If you trace around a modulus circle, it would imply the modulus operator does just wrap around smoothly, but if you look at the infinite slope on the graph it implies it does not. You might want to ask this question on the math overflow about what they consider to happen at the discontinuity. I'm curious too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are simply calculating the derivative for \$0<\theta_R<\pi\$, and not giving a solution for the points of discontinuity.

The discontinuity happens because the brushes transfer from one slip ring to the other at that angle. But the real physical system won't have a mathematical discontinuity there. There will be some dead zone where the brushes lose contact with either slip ring, or some more complicated transition if the brushes can contact both slip rings at the same time.

This analysis chooses to ignore this complexity and just give a solution for all the other rotation angles, which will give a useful approximation for the overall behavior of the motor.